# Proof of a maximal inequality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I am reading on martingale theory from "Probability: a graduate course" and where the following theorem is proved (in the proof, theorem $9.1$ refers to Doob's maximal inequality):

[image]

Do you have any idea how he obtained inequality $(1),$ especially how he obtained $\{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} c_kX_{k}^+>\lambda\}$ in the integral in inequality $(1)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Because of the following two things:

1. $\{c_k\}$ is not increasing so the integrand is less or equal than zero.
2. $Y_k \geq c_k X^+_k$ so $\{\max_{0 \leq k \leq n} c_k X^+_k > \lambda\} \subset \{\max_{0 \leq k \leq n} Y_k > \lambda\}$.

Comment: Do you think there is a typo while passing to inequality $(1)$ ? Instead of $c_j-c_{j-1}$ it should be $c_{j}-c_{j+1}$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Above where they define $Y_k$, it says $c_{j+1}$. The funny thing is that my answer was based on that. I missed the typo!, But it's clearly a typo. Also the summation starts in $j=0,$ so we would have a $c_{-1},$ which doesn't exist.

Comment: In this case, his argument is incorrect

Comment: what part of his argument is incorrect?

Comment: the passage to inequality $(1)$, especially that points 1. and 2. do not hold in this case (integral is positive)

Comment: Yes, you are right.